# Function send() not being called

Tags: javascript, html, discord, webhooks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://datasend94.epizy.com/scripts/script-1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="input1">
  <input id="input2">
  <button onclick="send('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/829815195274444830/4LAH1jKt34NjFyjgG0tHP8RfZIL9x3_rqa894BFpObvEjYdjq7UjuId-hauWqqiiX8xg')"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey, so right now I’m using this discord webhook sending js library, documentation is http://datasend94.epizy.com/documentation/. The problem is when I’m trying to call the function “send()” with the discord webhook inside of it, it will not call at all. Anyone know why? Browser is safari on mobile IOS.

Comment: Have you tested on other, especially desktop, browsers?

Comment: Yes, chrome doesn’t work either

Comment: Are you getting any error messages on the console? Have you checked the network tab of Chrome developer tools?

Comment: Nope none at all

Comment: How do you know the call doesn't happen?

Comment: I assume your page runs on http**s**? If so, the discord script will not get loaded. In a secure context you cannot load resources like scripts from unsecure sources (http).

Comment: I know the call doesn’t happen because I changed the code on the page since it’s my js library to alert on function but it doesn’t work. And yes, it is http.

Comment: It worked in my code editor but not on the web, so I’m not sure why.

Comment: I'm almost certain your real site will give you the same console error as your snippet here does when clicking the button: `"ReferenceError: send is not defined"` which is caused by the script not being loaded due to being located on an insecure location. Chrome's network tab will show you this problem.

Comment: I did get that error earlier, maybe that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is most probably caused by the discord script not being loaded due to security restrictions. In a page served via localhost or `https` you cannot load script resources from insecure `http` sources.

Check your Chrome's network tab in the developer tools (F12 on Windows):

[image]

The recommended solution is for you to copy that `script-1.js` into your own webservers webspace and serve it from there.